# Automatically increase stock after order - Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I manually manage my stocks on Prestashop. I am looking for a solution to automatically return the initial stock after a sales order.

For example, a product is ordered in two copies with an initial stock of 7. I would like the stock to remain at 7 after the order and not at 5.

Do you know a technique that would allow me to realize this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a Hook on Order Confirmation (displayOrderConfirmation) in a new module (you can generate one at https://validator.prestashop.com/) and check whats inside the cart then put it again in your stocks :

```
public function hookDisplayOrderConfirmation($params) {
    $order = $params['order'];
    $cart = new Cart($order->id_cart); 
    $products = $cart->getProducts(); 
    foreach ($products as $product) {
       $removed_qty = (int) $product['quantity'];
       $past_qty = (int) StockAvailable::getQuantityAvailableByProduct($product['id_product'], $product['id_product_attribute']);
       $new_qty = $removed_qty + $past_qty;
       StockAvailable::setQuantity($product['id_product'], $product['id_product_attribute'], $new_qty);
    }
}
```